# CSS - counter rotateX messes up on-hover effect

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transforms

So I want to create a set of buttons that satisfies the following properties:

- Shape is an isosceles trapezoid (this is currently achieved by `transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(-35deg)`
- On hover, the button background colour and text colour swap (currently achieved by on-hover code)
- Button text is not rotated whatsoever (currently achieved by a counter-rotation of `rotateX(35deg)` in the span)

So far, they look like this:
[Buttons before hovering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGKL7.png)

But upon hover, this happens, to all buttons:

[Button after hovering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgwsx.png)

From my testing, it's caused by the `btn-trapezoid-outline span` section of the code, but removing it leaves the text rotated in some way. Do you have any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Relevant code is below:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #121212;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
  }


  
  .btn-wrap{
    margin: 25px 0px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .btn{

    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .btn-trapezoid-outline{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fcec0c;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border: 1px solid #fcec0c;
    transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(35deg) translateZ(25px) translateY(14.4px);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    margin: 0px 30px;
    
  }

  .btn-trapezoid-outline span {
    display:inline-block;
    transform:perspective(200px) rotateX(-35deg);
      /* Safari */
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-35deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-35deg);
  /* Opera */
  -o-transform: rotateX(-35deg);
  /* IE */
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-35deg);
  }
  
  .btn-trapezoid-outline:hover{
    background: #fcec0c;
    color: #121212;
  }
```

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #121212;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
  }


  
  .btn-wrap{
    margin: 25px 0px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .btn{

    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .btn-trapezoid-outline{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fcec0c;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border: 1px solid #fcec0c;
    transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(35deg) translateZ(25px) translateY(14.4px);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    margin: 0px 30px;
    
  }

  .btn-trapezoid-outline span {
    display:inline-block;
    transform:perspective(200px) rotateX(-35deg);
      /* Safari */
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-35deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-35deg);
  /* Opera */
  -o-transform: rotateX(-35deg);
  /* IE */
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-35deg);
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  }
  
  .btn-trapezoid-outline:hover{
    background: #fcec0c;
    color: #121212;
  }
  .btn-trapezoid-outline:hover span {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-35deg) translateY(-5px);
  }
```

```html
<div class="btn-wrap">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-trapezoid-outline">
    <span>Link 1</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-trapezoid-outline">
    <span>Link 2</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-trapezoid-outline">
    <span>Link 3</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

The transform-style CSS property sets whether children of an element are positioned in the 3D space or are flattened in the plane of the element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style

so I think you need transform-style: preserve-3d; set to parent, I am guessing it is ".btn"

In my opinion it's all unnecessary to make Trapezoid shape because it can be done easily
https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

Edit: If you still want to use the same code for some reason, you can use translateY(-10px) to span on hover solve this quickly

Comment: I tried using the trapezoid button from that website but I never got it to look good. 

Also did you mean rotateX(-10px)?

Comment: sorry it's translateY(-10px), added a code snippet as well

Comment: _In my opinion it's all unnecessary to make Trapezoid shape because it can be done easily_ -- true, but the manner in which it is accomplished (in the provided link) uses borders in a manner that doesn't really allow you to place text content _within_ the trapezoid.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to the parent of `.btn-trapezoid-outline`.  Since you are applying transform and perspective on that element itself, it is only preserving 3d of its child elements, while it remains in a flat space

Here is the source documentation that explains why: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style

Comment: While this fixes the on-hover, it reintroduces the problem of the text being warped, see here: https://imgur.com/a/OQKXeGP